# Android Web View view port issue

Tags: android, html, mobile, android-webview, viewport

Android App has a button linking to web site. and When I  click button I can see web page on Android Web View.

When I visit web page via Android app. I want to see all of it like I am viewing a big desktop screen.

so I set view port width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980">
```

If i visit web page via mobile chrome browser. it is working properly. 
as below picture 
[image]

But if I visit web page via Android Web view. It fit to mobile device screen width
as below picture

[image]

I don't know why view port change i set. 
In addition, I am Using Galaxy S7.

please give any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not provide specific width to your content. Rather you can set width according to the corresponding device's pixel density.

You can create separate stylesheets for each density

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" href="hdpi.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.0)" href="mdpi.css" />
```

Or, specify the different styles in one stylesheet:

```
#header {
    background:url(medium-density-image.png);
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    /* CSS for high-density screens */
    #header {
        background:url(high-density-image.png);
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 0.75) {
    /* CSS for low-density screens */
    #header {
        background:url(low-density-image.png);
    }
}
```